# How to handle test tags/karate options from ci/cd gitlab?

Tags: cucumber, karate, bdd

I was trying to run the test from CI/CD gitlab runner file but it is causing issue while executing from gitlab.

I have sucessfully executed the test locally using the karate option

Working fine in Local Run:

mvn test -Dkarate.env=stg +-DKarate.options=--tags @Ui" -Dtest.run.mode=localtest -Dtest.run.group=OKCUtest -Dtest=OKCUtest -Dtest.gitlabRunner=false -DbuildDirectory=stg-target/OKCUtest -Dtest.run.testSource=localtest

There are 5 test feature files which were executed using the @Api tags and now I have identified that one should be @Ui and changed the respective feature file and created the new pipeline OKCU-UI and have updated the command line syntax to address @Ui tests.

Comment: this is impossible to diagnose remotely. see if this gives you any hints: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2164#issuecomment-1296951203

Answer (score 0):

can you try this command ?

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@Ui"
```

if still not try same command with version 0.9.6.RC3